# Core Data Performance: Establishing Relationships in willSave:

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have 3 entities:

`Ticket`
`Event` 
`Guest`

A Guest has many tickets. Ticket has one guest.

An event has many tickets.

An event has many guests and a guest has many events (based on a Ticket entity being clientDeleted = NO)

For my fetch request on Guest, I used to have a SUBQUERY on the predicate as such:

`NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(tickets, $ticket, $ticket.clientDeleted = NO AND $ticket.event = %@).@count > 0", event]`

Worked fine for five figures worth of Tickets. I need to do 100,000+ efficiently.

Now I have an idea to make an optimization: Denormalize in order to remove the SUBQUERY:

`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY events = %@", event"];`

I can do this by establishing the Guest<-->Event relationship in the Ticket.willSave core data hook:

```
- (void)willSave
{
  [super willSave];
  if (self.guest) {
    [self.guest updateEventRelationship:self.event];
  }
}
```

Guest.m:

```
- (void)updateEventRelationship:(Event *)event
{
    BOOL hasEvent = NO;

    NSSet *tickets = [self.tickets filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"event = %@", event]];

    for (Ticket *ticket in tickets) {
        if (!ticket.clientDeleted.boolValue) {
            hasEvent = YES;
            if (![self.events containsObject:event])
                [self addEventsObject:event];
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!hasEvent && [self.events containsObject:event]) [self removeEventsObject:event];

}
```

This works, however I did some Time Profiling on it using Instruments... and it's pretty darn slow during the containsObject call. Is there a better place I can put this code in the model level to be faster? Especially when bulk importing tickets?